# Random Number but Don't Repeat

Tags: vb.net, shuffle

I would like to generate a random number less than 50, but once that number has been generated I would like it so that it cannot be generated again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can only do that 50 times :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a random number.  Rather it is a random permutation of the numbers in the range 1-49 (or 0-49).

Answer (score 13):

Please see: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
public static void shuffle (int[] array) 
{
    Random rng = new Random();       // i.e., java.util.Random.
    int n = array.length;            // The number of items left to shuffle (loop invariant).
    while (n > 1) 
    {
        n--;                         // n is now the last pertinent index
        int k = rng.nextInt(n + 1);  // 0 <= k <= n.
        int tmp = array[k];
        array[k] = array[n];
        array[n] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with it for the past 15 minutes but cannot seem to figure out how to call it. I'm a bit new with vb.

Comment: Should rng.nextInt(n + 1) actually be rng.nextInt(n-1)?

Comment: @StevenT: No, not in C#

Answer (score 9):

Put the numbers 1-49 in a sortable collection, then sort it in random order; pop each one out of the collection as needed.

Comment: Erm.  "Sort in random order" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: True, my bad :-). Re-order at random?

Comment: The words your looking for are: "Place the numbers 1 through 50 in a collection, *shuffle*, then pop each out one at a time."

Comment: Bingo. (Pun intended.) +1 for Mitch for the real answer

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as the question was tagged VB/VB.Net... this is a VB implementation of Mitch's answer.

```
Public Class Utils

   Public Shared Sub ShuffleArray(ByVal items() As Integer)

      Dim ptr As Integer
      Dim alt As Integer
      Dim tmp As Integer
      Dim rnd As New Random()

      ptr = items.Length

      Do While ptr > 1
         ptr -= 1
         alt = rnd.Next(ptr - 1)
         tmp = items(alt)
         items(alt) = items(ptr)
         items(ptr) = tmp
      Loop

   End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code generate alpha-numeric string with length that you pass as parameter.

```
Public Shared Function GetRandomAlphaNumericString(ByVal intStringLength As Integer) As String

Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

Dim intLength As Integer = intStringLength - 1

Dim stringChars = New Char(intLength) {}

Dim random = New Random()

    For i As Integer = 0 To stringChars.Length - 1
        stringChars(i) = chars(random.[Next](chars.Length))
    Next

    Dim finalString = New [String](stringChars)
    Return finalString
End Function
```