# Pick a random number from a set of numbers

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have an array of integers like these;
dim x as integer()={10,9,4,7,6,8,3}.
Now I want to pick a random number from it,how can I do this in visual basic?Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218155/random-number-but-dont-repeat/1222514#1222514

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a random generator:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
```

Then you pick a random number that represents an index into the array:

```
Dim index As Integer = rnd.Next(0, x.Length)
```

Then you get the value from the array:

```
Dim value As Integer = x(index)
```

Or the two last as a single statement:

```
Dim value As Integer = x(rnd.Next(0, x.Length))
```

Now, if you also want to remove the number that you picked from the array, you shouldn't use an array in the first place. You should use a `List(Of Integer)` as that is designed to be dynamic in size.

Comment: Or, for the less verbose among us, can you use "dim value as integer = x(new random().next(0,x.length))" or is that considered too Java-ish for VB'ers? :-)

Comment: I'd go with "Hard to Maintain"

Comment: @paxdiablo: I avoided creating the Random object in the same statement because then it looks like you should create one for every random number that you want. If you pick numbers in a loop that would be bad, as the random generator is seeded using the system timer, so you would get the same random numbers over and over.

Answer (score 0):

randomly choose an index from 0 to length-1 from your array.