# VB.NET Generate unique 5 numbers between 1 and 10

Tags: vb.net, random

Hello I 5 unique numbers betwen 0 and 10, I'm doing as following :

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
For counter As Integer = 0 To 5
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 10)
    MsgBox(RandomNumber )
Next
```

Sometimes it works, I get those numbers : "1,7,4,9,3"
but sometimes I get a duplicate numbers like : "5,2,3,2,7"

How can I be sure to have unique numbers each time?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Number but Don't Repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218155/random-number-but-dont-repeat)

Comment: The number 10 is not included in the possible results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HashSet(Of Integer)` to *remember* numbers that have already been printed out:

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RememberSet As New HashSet(Of Integer)

Dim RandomNumber As Integer

While RememberSet.Count < 5
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 10)
    If RememberSet.Add(RandomNumber) Then
        MsgBox(RandomNumber)
    End If
End While
```

Comment: This results in loops that are longer than needed.  It works but it isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a different approach, make a list of integers from 0 to 10, use the random generator to get an index inside this list, print that number and remove from the list. Keep the generation of the random numbers inside the limits

```
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).ToList()
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomIndex As Integer
For counter As Integer = 1 To 5
    RandomIndex = RandomClass.Next(0, numbers.Count)
    MsgBox(numbers(RandomIndex))
    numbers.RemoveAt(RandomIndex)
Next
```

Comment: To make this clearer 10 - counter could be replaced with numbers.Count.

Comment: Oh yes, it is better, also Enumerable.Range is shorter

Comment: @dbasnett thanks for the fix, however there are still uncertainties like if the number 10 should be enclosed or not in the possible outputs. The OP should explain better, but now has already made ​​his choice...

Comment: agreed.  Their choice was not one that will scale well.

Comment: You could also do `var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).OrderBy(n => RandomClass.Next()).Take(5)` although it's probably not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a seed so that random numbers are not repeated.

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
Dim RememberSet As New HashSet(Of Integer)

Dim RandomNumber As Integer

While RememberSet.Count < 5
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 10)
    If RememberSet.Add(RandomNumber) Then
        MsgBox(RandomNumber)
    End If
End While
```

Comment: `Dim RandomClass As New Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks)` gives a `System.OverflowException`

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
 Sub Main()

    Dim a As String() = New String(2) {}
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Dim d As String = " "
    Do
        Console.Clear()
        Console.Write("Enter your name:")
        a(c) = Console.ReadLine()
        c += 1

    Loop Until c = 3
    For Each d In a
        Console.Write(" " & d)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```