# VB.NET array randomization

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of 6 elements , and I want to fill 18 textboxes with those members randomly each time . I want only to repeat the item 2 times . I have this code :

```
 FlatTextBox1.Text =   (subjects.Item(Int(Rnd() * (subjects.Count - 1))))
FlatTextBox2.Text =   (subjects.Item(Int(Rnd() * (subjects.Count - 1))))
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

That continues till the end . Now the problem is that some items get's repeated 3 times and others 1 time so there's no equality . How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You have 18 textboxes which should match with only 6 elements. Surely the elements have to repeat themselves, even after avoiding duplications. Or do you want to have equality(i.e. 3 elements by each textbox?)

Comment: A random number generator without any further restriction can output repeated numbers and you don't have any control on this. That's why when setting up a random number generator you have usually to add further means to avoid repetitions. As I understand from your code and from your description, you haven't done any work on this front and thus I am afraid that this is not how SO has to be used: work a bit by your own and come here back when you find problems. Quick ideas to start with: store all the generated numbers in a collection and check it every time a new number is generated to see...

Comment: ... the number of ocurrences; if the number does not pass the filtering, a new random number would have to be generated. This is usually done inside a loop. I guess that this is more than enough to get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Number but Don't Repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218155/random-number-but-dont-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you made a typo and wanted the items repeated 3 times, instead of 2, since 3*6=18:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private R As New Random
    Private subjects() As String = {"cat", "dog", "fish", "hamster", "lizard", "bird"}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        values.AddRange(subjects)
        values.AddRange(subjects)
        values.AddRange(subjects)

        Dim index As Integer
        Dim matches() As Control
        For i As Integer = 1 To 18
            index = R.Next(values.Count)
            matches = Me.Controls.Find("FlatTextBox" & i, True)
            matches(0).Text = values(index)
            values.RemoveAt(index)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hello, Yes I  wrote 2 instead of 3 lol . Thank you for this solution